# Ubuntu 上で Spresense 開発環境の構築 (OpenOCD)

Tags: ubuntu, spresense

現在Spresense開発環境の構築を行っているのですが、Unix系のOSは初めてのために手こずっています。

[Spresense SDK 開発ガイド](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-nuttx/nuttx-developer-guide)

上記ページの手順で「OpenOCDのインストール」の項目のリポジトリのダウンロードをした後、`configure` コマンドを実行しようとすると "ファイル、またはフォルダは存在しない" というメッセージで失敗します。

```
cd spresense-openocd
./configure --disable-target64
```

確かにconfigureというファイルもフォルダもspresense-openocdには存在しないのですが、
configure.acと言うスクリプトファイルっぽいのものがあったので以下の通り実行してみましたが、実行は出来ませんでした。

```
./configure.ac --disable-target64
sudo ./configure.ac --disable-target64
```

`./configure --disable-target64` というのは `./` が現在のフォルダを表していると思うのですが違ったりするのでしょうか？

Comment: `spresense-openocd` ディレクトリに `bootstrap` というファイルがありませんか？

Comment: ありました・・・が、./bootstrapとすると権限無し、sudo ./bootstrap とするとlLibrary is requiredとなります。何か足りないようなのですが・・・

Comment: `sudo apt install libtool` を実行してからもう一度 `sudo ./bootstrap` を実行してみて下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます。その後のconfigureとかも全部sudoにして権限を奪取しないとならなかったですがmakeまでは全部通りました

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt install libtool` を実行してから `spresense-openocd` ディレクトリで `sudo ./bootstrap` を実行してみて下さい。

<sub>-- この投稿は、[metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis) さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48008/ubuntu%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%AEspresense%E3%81%AE%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E3%81%AE%E6%A7%8B%E7%AF%89openocd#comment49580_48008)を元にコミュニティ wiki として投稿したものです。</sub>